# Are there any fusion reactions that reduce the number of baryons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, quarks, fusion

In the simplest of fusion reactions, two hydrogen nuclei fuse to form deuterium. Besides deuterium, we get a positron and an electron neutrino out of it. The positron combines with the extra electron to release gamma rays. But it seems the number of baryons is conserved. Are there any reactions where the number of baryons is reduced? I imagine that it's impossible to increase the number of baryons because....where would that energy come from.

Comment: Which electron?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the standard model goes, baryon number (really, quark number) is a strictly conserved quantum number of any system. Reactions in which extra baryons are produced would be classified under the label of "[baryogenetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis)". While many Grand Unified Theories have predictions of baryogenetic reactions, we have yet to find clear evidence of this actually happening (I'd be remiss if I didn't at least mention that baryogenesis can occur in the Standard Model through sphalerons, but this doesn't actually answer your question).

> I imagine that it's impossible to increase the number of baryons because....where would that energy come from.

I would like to point out that you can certainly create more quarks and antiquarks from reactions, as long as there is enough energy to do so, but in the particular reaction you describe, the energy difference between the initial and final state is about an order of magnitude lower than that which is required to produce a pion, the lightest meson state.

Comment: I thought quarks and antiquarks have not been observed.

Comment: I guess the LHC is destroying baryons all the time. But have they ever made any? Will the 'old one' be upset at our breaking his toys?

Comment: @aquagremlin while it’s true that quarks and antiquarks cannot be observed alone, there is evidence that protons and neutrons have some internal structure, or that they are not elementary, mostly in predicted cross sections from various reactions. As for whether the LHC is destroying baryons all the time (or making them), the LHC neither destroys nor creates them. Protons and antiprotons have complementary baryon number (+1 and -1), so an p-pbar reaction has net zero baryon loss. And of course CERN can create as many baryons as it wants as long as it creates that many antibaryons.

Comment: but when two protons collide at the LHC, they are destroyed and you get other stuff. not protons or neutrons. So isnt the LHC destroying baryons?

Comment: @aquagremlin my bad, I forgot the LHC does proton-proton collisions, not proton-antiproton. Either way, they don't violate baryon number conservation, they often don't publish their entire final states because they study "jets" which require a lot more analysis than a simple list of particles would. But whatever particles are in their final state, there must be a net baryon number of 2 (one for each proton in the initial state).